# How do I setup a domain using Amazon AWS Route 53 ? (EC2 AMI + Route53 + Godaddy-domain)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 server. I want to connect it with my Godaddy domain.

**This is what I did till now:**

- I have a domain signed on Godaddy.
- I have an EC2 server with a website running on it.
- I defined the domain on Route 53 (created a "Record Set" that is: example.com):
- Created a new Record Set for MX (which is very important for me!)
- Created a new Record Set IPV4 that uses the Public IP of my EC2 server as a value).
- Pasted the 4 DNSs from the NS Record Set row on my Godaddy account instead the existing standard ones.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/POLUc.png
[image]

**Results**:

- My website loads as: example.com - Check!
- I get Emails (myname@example.com) without any problems - Check!

**The Problem: My website doesn't load when running 'www' before the domain: www.example.com**

I was googling for some answers and found a lot of ways to handle domains. Some of them were even very strange (like pointing to other IP addresses which doesn't answer my question), and some were very simple that work **only** with static content with the S3.

Bottom line questins:

What is the normal best way to make an external domain (from Godaddy for this case) link with my EC2 server + MX working + getting the website loading with or without the 'www' ?

** It must be without creating a 'www' **sub-domain** for - SEO reasons.

I hope my question is well explained. 
If not please comment and I will edit and add information/PrtScns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with DNS.

Your webserver is probably using Virtual Hosts and isn't configured to serve the site on www.example.com

If its Apache try:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

(presuming of course that a DNS record exists for www.example.com)

Comment: I'm new to all the Amazon AWS. 
How do I set these on Apache ?

Comment: Are you definitely using Apache? If so, these commands would be part of a <VirtualHost> directive in your config. Plenty of Google reference on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

just create an A record with www (www.example.com) and pointed to the EC2 IP

Answer (score 0):

Change your current functioning redirect to include the WWW, then follow these steps:

I just managed to figure this out yesterday:

Go to you S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home and click Create Bucket. For Bucket Name enter in your naked domain name, eg for www.example.com, you would put just example.com.

Click on the magnifying glass icon next to your newly created bucket. On the menu that appears select Static Website Hosting, then click on 'Redirect all requests to another host name'. The textbox that appears should now be prepopulated with the text www.example.com. Select save.

Open your Route 53 hosted zone at https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home. Select your domain and click on Create Record Set. Leave the Name area blank, and leave the default type at 'A - IPv4 address'. Select Yes for Alias, and click on the Alias Target textbox. At this point a dropdown menu should appear in which you can select the S3 Website Endpoint you created in steps 1 and 2.

Lastly, click create, and enjoy your new routing set-up!